# C++ class whose member is a struct: Cannot understand compiler error

Tags: c++, class, struct, compiler-errors

I want to create a class one of whose `private:` members is a `struct point`(see below). The public members `ndim` and `numparticles` are
set at run-time by the user, which are used to create corresponding arrays inside the class . However I am getting a compiler error. I don't understand where I messed up.

The compiler error being displayed:

```
nbdsearch.h:25: error: ‘point’ does not name a type
nbdsearch.h:24: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘nbdsearch::ndim’
nbdsearch.h:31: error: from this location
nbdsearch.h:31: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

The class code:

```
class nbdsearch{
 public: 
  int ndim,numparticles;
  point particlevec[numparticles];


 private: 
  struct point{
    string key;
    double cood[ndim];
              };

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> nbdsearch.h:31: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token

```
double cood[ndim];
```

Array size needs to be a compile time constant and `ndim` clearly isn't. `ndim` is a variable.

> error: ‘point’ does not name a type

```
point particlevec[numparticles];
```

On line 25, compiler doesn't know what `point` is. The structure is defined at a later point. Compilers in C++ work on a top to bottom approach(Not sure whether C++0X relaxes this rule). So, what ever types being used should be known to it before hand.

Try this -

```
class nbdsearch{
 private: 
  struct point{
    string key;
    std::vector<double>cood;
  };
 public: 
    int ndim,numparticles;
    std::vector<point> particlevec;   
};
```

Comment: You mean I cannot create an C++ array of user specified size?

Comment: **Variable length arrays** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array arenot allowed in C++.

Comment: The link seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

`point` needs to be declared before its use. Try putting the `private:` block before the `public:` block.

Comment: I thought within a class the order of the public and private sections was irrelevant.

Comment: For functions and members, that tends to be true.  On the other hand, types always have to be at least forward declared before use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different problems with your code.

1. The declaration of `point` needs to be visible to compiler before
   you use it
2. You're trying to create array from variables that are not compile time constants; C++ does not allow creation of variable length arrays.

To fix these problems:

1. Move the declaration block for `point` above where you use it. Note that since the definition of `point` is `private`, someone calling `nbdsearch::particlevec` will not be able to store that value. All they could do is pass it along to another member function (or `friend` function) of `nbdsearch`.
2. Change declaration of `particlevec` to `std::vector<point> particlevec`. Make a similar change for `point::cood`. Once the user specifies values for `ndim` & `numparticles` use `std::vector::resize` to size the arrays appropriately.

Comment: The C99 feature is to support variable-length arrays of automatic (i.e. local non-static) storage class.  Not variable-sized members.